# Javascript Custom Array.prototype.method logs 'not defined'

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

So, I've never done this before, trying to add a method to the Array.prototype.  See console.log statement below for usage.   It keeps telling me the method is not defined.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Help!

My best conclusion / guess so far is that "this" is referring to the global object, and that's screwing it up somehow.   But how to fix that, no clue.  :(

```
const solution = input =>{
  
  Object.defineProperty(
      Array.prototype, 'polyReverse', {
        value: () => this ? (polyReverse(this.substr(1)) + this[0]) : (this),
        configurable: true, writable: true  
      }
  );

  console.log("string".split("").polyReverse().join(""));

};
/*****
 * 
 * ReferenceError: polyReverse is not defined
 *   at Array.value (main.js on line 4:20)
 * 
 * 
 *///////
```

NOTE:  I also tried this for the value of value..

```
value: () => this ? (this.substr(1).polyReverse() + this[0]) : (this),
```

and this ...

```
value: () => this ? (this.polyReverse(this.substr(1)) + this[0]) : (this),
```

with no luck

Comment: Don’t use an arrow function here

Comment: Well, I see no definition of `polyReverse` in the code you've shared...

Comment: Also, [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/215552)

Comment: An arrow function for a method will use the lexical value of `this` from your declaration enviroinment, NOT the object reference that came with the method call.  Moral of the story - **methods should not be declared as arrow functions**.  Arrow functions are not just a shortcut syntax, they also have different behavior for the `this` value and a few other differences related to function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and was able to resolve the issue of `not defined`

```js
Array.prototype.polyReverse = function(value) {
  return this ? (this.substr(1).polyReverse() + this[0]) : (this)
};

console.log("string".split("").polyReverse().join(""));
```

Beyond this your logic seems to have some issue and it is throwing an error. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with `polyReverse`, so you would be the best person to fix that logic.

Since you specifically asked about the `not defined` issue, the above snippet should solve your problem and help you proceed further to fixing the logic

Answer (score 0):

So based on advice from helpful folks here, I was able to fix the problem as everyone said,  do not use arrow functions.  YES!   Also, took note of how extending native methods is BAD!  And I will make a sub class to do this now.

Thanks all for help.

Working code ...

```
const solution = input =>{
  
  Object.defineProperty(
      Array.prototype, 'polyReverse', {
        value: function() {
          console.log(this); 
          return (this.length > 0 ? 
           (this.join("").substr(1).split("").polyReverse() + this[0]) : 
           (this)
          )},
        configurable: true, 
        writable: true  
      }
  );

  console.log("string".split("").polyReverse());

};
```